# How do I disable mobile Youtube redirection on iPad?

Tags: ipad, youtube

When I click a Youtube link, say, in the newly released Skype app, the iPad will open the link in Safari, which will load the mobile site. Also in Twitter's built in browser the mobile site is displayed. This sucks, because the site is slow and often fails loading a video at all.

Is there a way to stop Youtube redirecting to m.youtube.com on iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no, you can't stop it. It's Google re-directing you.

You can work around it though. You can scroll down to the very bottom of the page and tap the "desktop" link, which will take you to the full desktop version of the site. If what you want is the YouTube app to open, then all you can do is copy the name of the video from safari into the YouTube app.

I know what you mean about it not loading the videos. It's annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Mobile seems to work better for me on my iPad, yet they keep redirecting me to the desktop version. I clicked it once to check messages because apparently you can't do that on mobile anymore.

They seriously discriminate against non desktop users. We can't watch half the videos because of restrictions. We can't even check messages now the app is dreadful it randomly changes quality of video to the lowest possible definition in the middle of a video. It seriously puts me off! My advice for you, however, tell YouTube you want it to redirect you to mobile version. 99.9% of the time they do the opposite to what you ask, so it should work!

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck the other way around and was looking how to prevent from redirecting to desktop on mobile and found following answer in te thread [We've redirected you to the desktop website. Return to mobile YouTube.](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/4180562?hl=en):

> Switch to Mobile:
>
> https://m.youtube.com/?app=m&persist_app=1
>
> Switch to Desktop:
>
> https://youtube.com/?app=desktop&persist_app=1
>
> Save both links as bookmarks and you'll be able to switch that way.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings, tap on General, tap on Restrictions, enable Restrictions if you haven’t already, and disallow YouTube.

Doing so has the dual benefit of redirecting all YouTube links to the mobile website and hiding the native app on the device, clearing up more space for apps you actually want to use.

Answer (score -1):

Try YouTube link on chrome instead of safari also enable open links in chrome setting in YouTube app of iPad.